# how to enable developer options on an Android touchscreen

Tags: android, touchscreen

I have a large HDi touchscreen with Android 5.1 installed. I need to enable the developer options to use the device with Android Studio for debugging, however there is no "About this device" options in settings, it only gives CPU, GPU, Memory, Available/total and Android version.
Does anyone know how I can access the developer options on this device?
Google Play/store doesn't recognise it, so I can't install any of the ADB over network apps.

Comment: Ask the device manufacturer.

Comment: What manufacturer is the device from?

Comment: I have (and do) RTFM. I asked the Q because for some devices there are generic ways to do things, and the same Q was asked for Android TVs (without agressive responses - but no answers either). I've been given the (unbadged) device as a prototype to develop for, however I can probably work my way back up the supply chain to find out who makes it and go from there.

Comment: actually I didn't need to  - the answer is here in case anyone else needs it - ADB over TC/IP <http://www.mikevandrongelen.info/2015/12/apps-on-big-screen-iii-debugging-android-tv.html>